Is it a sin to refuse to give help, even for someone having no loss or trouble doing so?
Is it a sin to refuse to give help, even for someone having no loss or trouble doing so?
An extreme example: in a freezing cold climate, you have a fire going on and someone else comes to ask you for an ember to make his own fire going again.
